# virtual inheritance doesn't work on specific g++ version

Tags: c++, g++

Here is perfectly valid code in C++

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a) {}
};


class B : A {
public:
    B(int a) : A(a) {}
};

class C : B {

    C(int a) : B(a) {}
};
```

However, when I change inheritance of class B to virtual:

```
class B : virtual A {
public:
    B(int a) : A(a) {}
};
```

I get

```
$ g++ som.h
som.h: In constructor ‘C::C(int)’:
som.h:14:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
C(int a) : B(a) {}
              ^
```

The strangest is on my friend's PC it compiles (she has g++ 7.3 version and ubuntu 18). I have g++ 5.5 and ubuntu 16.

Could someone explain me why does this happen?

Comment: Are you aware that your inheritance is `private`?

Comment: @r3musn0x I have the same behavior and to put all public changes nothing

Comment: @r3musn0x that time yes, this is disturbing because there is no diamond in that case

Comment: @bruno, as far as I know, the most derived class should initialize the virtual base regardless whether inheritance is diamond or not.

Comment: @r3musn0x exactely

Comment: @bruno, the other question is whether it can actually do this (call virtual base constructor) when the inheritance is private. That's why I was trying to find out whether the private inheritance was intentional.

Comment: only him knows, but probably he just missed to specify the visibility :-)

Comment: That's right, I just forgot that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need :

```
class C : public B {
public:
   C(int a) : A(a), B(a) {} // in that order
};
```

as  r3mus n0x says in remark, the most derived class should initialize the virtual base regardless whether inheritance is diamond or not.

morality : if you don't have a diamond do not use virtual inheritance